# Stack memory allocation in recursion

Tags: recursion, stack

I was asked to write a recursive function without boundary condition. And then, I was asked that whether it is possible to bound the allocation of memory to the stack being created so that the computer do not hang. If yes, then how?

Comment: All these questions were asked to you ! Then what do you want from here ?

Comment: "without boundary condition" ? so it is infinite recursion function that never return?

Comment: I want to know that if it possible then how? I didn't answered this question that time.

Answer (score 0):

2 assumptions. "Without boundary condition" means infinite recursion. "Computer hang" means stack overflow or app crash. Computer will always "hang" when you give CPUs infinite loops to work on.

There is no stack being created. It is there and when you execute a recursive call, you allocate space there, (*now, here I might be wrong*) for the arguments, return value, and the point to return to, and maybe some more ([wiki:callstack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)). What is created are those stack frames, that contain the context information.

You can make space needed for args and return 0. But I think it's impossible to skip the return point. So you will always need non-zero memory, for each level of recursion.

The only way to make infinite recursion possible, with out getting a stack overflow is to make the needed stack frame size 0, which I do not see possible.

Answer (score 0):

They may be referring to [tail call elimination or optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

If a language allocates a frame with every function call, recursion can often cause a "stack overflow".  However, most recursion based languages eliminate the frame allocation in a tail call.  If no additional memory is allocated during the execution of the function implementing the tail call, then you will run without increasing memory allocation.